# Is it recommended to reuse reference variables or to prevent reuse?

Tags: java

In the following code `node` has been reused. Now is it fine to keep it as it is Or is it recommended to create a new reference variabled say `nodePopped` ?

```
  public void preOrder(TreeNode node) {   
        final Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
        do {
            System.out.println(node.item);

            while (node != null) {
                stack.push(node.left); // just like a function call
            }

            node = stack.pop();   // OR TreeNode nodePopped = stack.pop() ? 
            if (node.right != null) {
                stack.add(node);
            }

        } while (!stack.isEmpty());
    }
```

If the code has bugs please ignore, please focus only on the question that has been asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"Is it recommended to reuse reference variables or to prevent reuse?"` -- It's recommended to write clean, understandable, reusable code.

- Use local variables when it makes logical sense to use them and higher scoped variables when it makes sense to use them.
- Use of local variables of the most limited scope possible is probably a good thing since they get cleaned up when their declared block goes out of scope.
- Although this is not always true for the objects that they reference since variables != objects. Make sure that you fully understand the difference between a reference variable and a reference or object.
- Don't worry about premature optimization.
- But do profile time critical code.
- Worry most about whether others will understand your code, or perhaps more importantly whether *your future self* will understand your code 1 year from now.

Comment: *"Worry about whether others or more importantly your future self will understand your code 1 year from now."* - Ahhhh, I'm so screwed ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: LOL, and nah!

Answer (score 0):

My own feeling is that if I'm looking at a function written by someone else that has a parameter, and for whatever reason I start by looking down toward the bottom of the function and see the parameter used, I tend to assume that the parameter at the bottom is going to be the parameter passed into the function.  Thus, if there's a statement that assigns to the parameter somewhere in the middle that assigns to the parameter (which, of course, doesn't change the actual *parameter* but rather a temporary variable that starts out with the parameter value), it can be confusing.  For that reason, my preference is to declare a local variable in a case like this (like `nodePopped`).  It's partly a style issue, but I've found that it works for me, and that I've had problems in the past reading others' code when they modify parameters.